# Somebody downvotes my old answers en masse and without any reason

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Is that normal? Should I take some action on it? How to figure out who is it?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/68714/gena2x?tab=reputation

Comment: btw, it's always good to wait 48 h hours, usually the anti-vote bot takes action in that timeframe

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't find out who it is as all votes are kept anonymous.

It's not normal or welcome for someone to go round down- (or indeed up-) voting posts from specific users. You should be voting based on the content. There are scripts in place to detect what we call serial voting where there are a large number of votes from one user to another over a short period of time (where "large" and "small" are numbers not known to anyone outside the development team), but it's possible that some votes will fall outside these values and go undetected.

If you spot something you think is suspicious then you should flag one of your posts for moderator attention using the "other" flag and explain that you think you're a victim of vote abuse.

There are tools available to moderators where we (I'm a mod elsewhere) can spot voting *trends* and this will confirm (or not) if there is targeted voting going on. If that's the case we can ask the team for those votes to be invalidated and then send the perpetrator a message and even suspend them if the vote abuse is serious enough.

Comment: And indeed, the serial downvotes now seem to have been reversed (2014-08-20 12:05:14Z).

Comment: I discovered this post while educating myself on the issue. The [help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) specifically directs end users: "If, after 24 hours, you do not see any fix to your reputation, please contact the team using the "contact us" form located at the bottom of any page." I wonder if that page needs updating?